# Putting Images Inside a BUTTON Element (HTML & CSS)

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, button

I have a simple button (as shown below) on which I need to display two pictures, one on either side of the button text. Im battling to create the CSS that will work in both Firefox and Internet Explorer! (the button images are coming from a JQuery UI skin file)

**CSS**

```
button div{
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_d19405_256x240.png);      
}

button div.leftImage{
    background-position: -96px -112px;
    float: left;
}

button div.rightImage{
    background-position: -64px -16px;
    float: right;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button><div class="leftImage"></div><span>Button Text</span><div class="rightImage"></div></button>
```

**Preview**

Firefox

[image]

Internet Explorer 8

[image]

Comment: Your classes in the html are different to the CSS...

Comment: describe the actual problem a bit .. what happens differently between the browsers ?

Comment: I'm just saying that the example doesn't make sense. You've created "leftimage" and "rightimage" classes in your CSS, but you're using "leftpic" and "rightpic" in your html.

Comment: @Bruce: Apologies, div class names corrected

Comment: @Gaby: Please see the problems (and differences) in the pictures I have posted. Im hoping im not the first person ever to try this and someone can post their successful code!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is how to do it

**The Theory**

Block elements (like DIV) although displayed in order of creation, will position themselves adjacent to the previous element or when short of space, on the next line. Because we dont want to give the button a width (we want the button to be automatically sized based on the content of the button) the block elements continued to appear on the next line (see IE8 image in the question above). Using `white-space:nowrap` forces inline elements (like SPAN and EM) to be displayed on the same line, but is ignored by block elements, hence the solution below.

**CSS**

```
button{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family:Lucida Sans MS, Tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000; 
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:auto;
    overflow:visible;
    height:28px;
}

button em{
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:0 2px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_3d3d3d_256x240.png);      
}

button em.leftImage{
    background-position: -96px -112px;
}

button em.rightImage{
    background-position: -64px -16px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button><em class="leftImage"></em>Button<em class='rightImage'></em></button>
```

**The Result**

Internet Explorer 6, 7, 8 and Firefox 1.5, 2, 3

[image]

Comment: This should be updated so as not to use the `<em>` element incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

I would use spans not divs for the image containers, since you seem to want the images to appear inline.  Using floated divs is just too complex.

In fact, you could probably simplify things further by applying one background image to the button itself, and one to the button-text span, and removing the other two containers altogether.

Another alternative is to simply add the images in as img tags.

Comment: I tried using SPAN elements for the images but (cleverly) Firefox hides them all of a sudden! Very strange - I love to hate CSS :'(

Comment: You'll need to give them some comntent (like an &nbsp;) and/or specify an absolute width/height to hold them open.  Empty elements collapse.

Comment: SPAN elements with a width and height of 16px (same as the DIV used) and with &nbsp; still werent being displayed in Firefox. I ended up using EM elements (see below). IMG tags cant use the JQuery skin image file as required for these buttons so I didnt even try to use them, although Im sure they WOULD work.

Answer (score 0):

try resetting the button css.

```
button{
border:none;
background:none;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

And add a space inside an empty DIV see if it works.

```
<button><div class="leftPic">&nbsp;</div><span>Button Text</span><div class="rightPic">&nbsp;</div></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can strip off the button tag and use a div tag instead.For other button action use javascript onlick() function and use css to change curser on hover(to make it look like button).For my project I used a similar approach.This may help you  :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is already solved, but just wanted to add that an easy way to put more than 1 image in a button is creating 1 .png with the dimensions of the button you want to create and the to elements together in one file.