# CSS buttons with 2 background colors

Tags: css, button, colors, background

I am having a problem with creating a button that has 2 colors with 3 states with a structure as follows:

| bgcolor1 (white-text) | bgcolor2 (white-arrow) | normal state

| bgcolor2 (white-text) | bgcolor2 (white-arrow) | hover state

| bgcolor3 (white-text) | bgcolor4 (white-arrow) | active state

my approach was to use the main color as bg color, and make the arrow with the seperate background color a background image. The problem I had there was with the third state of the arrow, which had a different background color.

could this be achieved with pure css?

can use a single code snippet for buttons with both single line and multiple line text?

thank you for your time on helping!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<button>` element, with tags (e.g. images or spans) inside it. This answer, although solving a different problem, might be of some help: [Putting Images Inside a BUTTON Element (HTML & CSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616775/putting-images-inside-a-button-element-html-css).

Comment: how can I change 2 background colors simultaneously, without using javascript? What is the advantage of using button instead of an anchor?

Comment: ok I got the answer from some other place, if anyone else was having the same problem they could use this link
http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?823862-CSS-buttons-with-2-background-colors&p=5047435&posted=1#post5047435